# Simulate userScrolling in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working on a chat app , initially I fetch only 100 message from the database. As the user scroll , I fetch the message from database and reload the table , to maintain the scroll position , after reloading the table , manually set the content offset , Scrolling position is working fine but tableview scrolling gets stopped so user feel jerk. I don't want user to feel that messages are fetched and table has reloaded. How to resume the stopped scrolling. When user manually scroll the table I get the direction and velocity using panGestureRecognizer property of UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you wish to implement a paging mechanism in your table view. when the user reaches the beginning of the scroll view, the next page is fetched, and that makes jolty experience.
My suggestion is to test `tableView.contentOffset.y` against some constant threshold while the user is scrolling. when the `contentOffset.y` past this threshold, you fetch the next page.

You can implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` in order to get the contentOffset and compare it to your threshold.
That way, the data would be fetched before (to an extent) the user reaches the end of the tableView.

```
private let fetchThreshold: CGFloat = 80
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height - fetchThreshold {
        /* Fetch next page.
         Remember to lock the process so the data won't be fetched multiple times. Use a boolean...
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have implemented the paging it it working fine. Only problem is scrolling gets stoped and user has to scroll again.

Comment: In my chat app this trick did the drill (in condition that the next page data is already available when the user reaches the end of the scrollView).

Comment: I have implemented in the same way. I prefetch the data before user reached to end of scrolling. Only problem is -setContentOffset. After setting the content offset to restore the scroll position, scrolling gets stopped.

Comment: Why do you use -setContentOffset? Is the data inserted at the beginning of the data source that causes the tableView to lose it's original offset?

Comment: I can not insert data at the beginning because of some business logic. This is why i reload the table,and use -setContentOffset method.

Comment: @AashishNagar When i first started implementing the chat mech', i looked into some interesting ideas about how to implement chat tableView. I got some from: https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController
The developers came up with some interesting chat implementation by 
 transforming the tableView and each cell vertically, and also invert the datasource, so that everything is presented backwards and reloadData doesn't requires them to use setContentOffset manually. Check it out i u wish. 
Best of luck!